# How to disable controller scheme in unity

Tags: unity

I"m using new input system for my top down shooter to set up both gamepad and Keyboard&mouse. When I just use one of these two schemes, everything is fine. But when I switch to other one, somethimes the keyboard scheme won’t work (it stops moving the player or move in some small pixels then stops again). The gamepad on the other hand is always good.

is there any way to disable one scheme while using the other one and vice versa?

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {

[SerializeField] float playerSpeed = 5f;
[SerializeField] float controllerDeadzone = 0.1f;
[SerializeField] float gamepadRotationSmoothing = 1000f;
[SerializeField] bool isGamepadActive;
[SerializeField] GameObject bullet;
[SerializeField] Transform bulletDirection;
Rigidbody2D _rigidbody2D;
PlayerInput playerInput;
Controllers controllers;
Vector2 movement;
Vector2 aim;

private void Awake()
{
    _rigidbody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    playerInput = GetComponent<PlayerInput>();
    controllers = new Controllers();
}

void OnEnable()
{
    controllers.Enable();
}

void OnDisable()
{
    controllers.Disable();
}

private void Start()
{
    controllers.Controls.Shoot.performed += _ => PlayerShoot();
    
}

private void PlayerShoot()
{
    GameObject g = Instantiate(bullet, bulletDirection.position, bulletDirection.rotation);
    g.SetActive(true);
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    HandleInput();
    HandleMovement();
    HandleRotation();
}



private void HandleInput()
{
    movement = controllers.Controls.Movement.ReadValue<Vector2>();
    aim = controllers.Controls.Aim.ReadValue<Vector2>();


}

private void HandleMovement()
{
    Vector2 move = new Vector2(movement.x, movement.y);
    _rigidbody2D.velocity = move * playerSpeed;
}

private void HandleRotation()
{

    if (isGamepadActive)
    {
        Vector2 playerDirection = new Vector2(aim.x, aim.y);
        float rotationDegree = Mathf.Atan2(playerDirection.y, playerDirection.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90f;

        if (Mathf.Abs(aim.x) > controllerDeadzone || Mathf.Abs(aim.y) > controllerDeadzone)
        {
            if (playerDirection.sqrMagnitude > 0.0f)
            {
                Quaternion gamepadRotationAngle = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, rotationDegree);
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, gamepadRotationAngle, gamepadRotationSmoothing);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (aim != new Vector2(0, 0))
        {
            Vector3 mouseWorldPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(aim);
            Vector3 targetDirection = mouseWorldPosition - transform.position;
            float mouseRotationAngle = Mathf.Atan2(targetDirection.y, targetDirection.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90f;
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, mouseRotationAngle));
        }

    }
}

public void OnDeviceChange(PlayerInput pi)
{
    isGamepadActive = pi.currentControlScheme.Equals("Gamepad") ? true : false;
    
}}
```

Comment: Have you tried to see if you have the same problem by switching the current wanted input over some UI/ Button/ Flag? `OnDeviceChange` might trigger on new added devices, this can mean turning controller on/ off or even adding something else.

Comment: Sounds to me like you might have some drift in the controller's analog sticks outside the deadzone, so the game keeps thinking the controller is providing input and switching to listen to it instead of the keyboard.